# Changing the name of a dataframe with an = sign in it

Tags: r, quantmod

My question is regarding changing the name of a dataframe that I imported using the quantmod package. I ran the following lines,

library(quantmod)
data <- getSymbols("GBP=x", from = "2013-01-01", to = "2017-06-01", src="yahoo")

Which then saved the data as GBP=x
I now want to change the name of this dataframe to something called "GBP".
I keep getting values and not a dataframe.

GBP    GBP=x

When I run GBP <- as.data.frame('GBP=x') I just get a dataframe with the value of GBP=x - 1 observation of 1 variable.

Any help is much appreciated

(Alternatively if you can suggest a way to download FX data from quantmod storing it as a more convenient name that would do the trick also.

Comment: `GBX = \`GBX=x\``

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the documentation correctly,

```
data <- getSymbols("GBP=x", from = "2013-01-01", to = "2017-06-01", src="yahoo",auto.assign=FALSE)
```

will result in the FX data being stored in **data**.

Also, in case you have trouble finding the ` key, it's on the top left of most keyboards. It's used generally in R to enclose troublesome characters.

Comment: Thanks for your input, and for giving me a little more knowledge on the auto.assign fuction! My keyboard is a Spanish one so its on the right of the keyboard, the second button from the enter key. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, This is what I use as well. It's a better practice than renaming the data frame at a later time. @user113156 But I would suggest using as well the option `return.class = "xts" ` so the function returns an xts "table" which is better to handle time series.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use '`':

```
GBP = `GBP=X`

# remove the original dataframe from your workspace
rm(`GBP=X`)
```